# return a href false back to true

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.popBox', function(){
    //get a href url and load content into popBox

    $('.close').click(function(){
        //close popBox
    });

    return false;//disable href go next page
});
```

I have `<a>`, when user click, popBox will open and load content from href's url.

I put return false to disable href go next page.

my problem is when i close the popBox and try to click the `<a>` again, it stay false and the popBox wont open again, is any way to turn it back?

Comment: you want to navigate to a different page if the popBox is not visible?
Can you show the html of the anchor tag?

Comment: <a href='logIn.php' class='popBox'>

Comment: You're rebinding the `click` handler to the `.close` elements every time you click the `.popBox`. Why? In any case, how is the handler supposed to know when you want the popup, and when you want to go to the next page?

Comment: ...wait, part of your question sounds like you want to go to the next page on the next click of the link after seeing the popup, and part of your question sounds like you want to see the popup again. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `e.preventDefault();` to stop the link going to a page.

I believe you also want to add some sort of toggle to open and close the popup within the same function. Instead of having another click function within to close.

You could do this with an `active` class. An example is below:

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.popBox', function(e){
    //prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.your-pop-box').toggleClass('active');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="popBox">Fire The Pop up</a>
<div class="your-pop-box">
    <p>Pop up content.</p>
    <p>Pop up content.</p>
    <p>Pop up content.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.your-pop-box {
    display: none;
}
.your-pop-box.active {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Here is a Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gz4qq/)**

Comment: `returns false` does that - it stops propagation and prevents default action

Comment: @ArunPJohny Would you say `return false;` is better to use than `e.preventDefault();` in this case?

Comment: same result, when i close the box and try again, it wont open again

Comment: not but if `return false` is not working then `e.preventDefault();` also should not work

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked.